# On content edit, how can I check/select a bool field based on which tab is active?

Tags: 8, theming, entities, javascript

I have a content type with a paragraph that has two fields, each field inside its own tab controlled by the form display like so:

[image: showing tabbed form display]

Here is what the set of tabbed fields looks like when editing a piece of content of the content type:

[image: single tab display on content edit]

[image: multi tab display on content edit]

The paragraph also has a bool field called field_active_callout_tab with two values: 'Single' and 'Multi', same as the tabs.

If the 'Single' tab is clicked, I want the bool to be checked. If the 'Multi' tab is selected, I want the bool to be unchecked.

I tried to use the Conditional Fields module, but it will not allow control by tab label. How can I establish this dependency between the tab and the bool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with jQuery, something like this should do it:

```
$('.single-class').click(function () {
    $('.bool-class').prop('checked', true);
});
$('.multi-class').click(function () {
  $('.bool-class').prop('checked', false);
});
```

Comment: thanks for that! Can you please explain where this jquery should go? Do I need to put it in a js file and then reference it from the paragraph template, or can I add it directly into the paragraph twig template? Further, are these classes assumed to be added on the fields / tab labels directly in manage form display?

Comment: You must define a library in your module, it is explained how to do it here https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module. The class names you find by inspecting the element in the browser, for further information on how to do that look here https://www.lifewire.com/get-inspect-element-tool-for-browser-756549

Comment: I'm not using a module to control the banner, just a twig template. Do you think I should add a custom JavaScript file to the theme and reference it from within the twig file?

Comment: Yes you shall add it to the theme, it is actually the same procedure look here, https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme